# ASP.NET core with MVC folder pathing/mapping FAIL

Tags: asp.net, dictionary, path

Whenever I upload a file I want to have it automatically converted into `.pdf` (I am doing that using NuGet). The thing is the upload scheme is done using relative paths. I do not know what to put into these parentheses:

```
var wordDocument = appWord.Documents.Open(uploadedFile);
```

What should I replace `uploadedFile` with in order to work? I will leave my relative path mapping code below:

```
public IActionResult Index1()
        {
            // Get files from the server
            var model = new FilesViewModel();
            foreach (var item in Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "upload")))
            {
                

                

                model.Files.Add(
                    new FileDetails { Name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item), Path = item });
            }
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index1(IFormFile[] files)
        {
            // Iterate each files
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                // Get the file name from the browser
                var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

                // Get file path to be uploaded
                var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "upload", fileName);

                // Check If file with same name exists and delete it
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
                {
                    System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
                }

                // Create a new local file and copy contents of uploaded file
                using (var localFile = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(filePath))
                using (var uploadedFile = file.OpenReadStream())


                {
                    var appWord = new Application();
                    if (appWord.Documents != null)
                    {
                        //yourDoc is your word document
                        var wordDocument = appWord.Documents.Open(uploadedFile);
                        string pdfDocName = "pdfDocument.pdf";
                        if (wordDocument != null)
                        {
                            wordDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat(pdfDocName,
                            WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF);
                            wordDocument.Close();
                        }
                        appWord.Quit();
                    }
                    uploadedFile.CopyTo(localFile);
                }
            }
            ViewBag.Message = "Files are successfully uploaded";

            // Get files from the server
            var model = new FilesViewModel();
            foreach (var item in Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "upload")))
            {
                model.Files.Add(
                    new FileDetails { Name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item), Path = item });
            }
            return View(model);
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Download(string filename)
        {
            if (filename == null)
                return Content("filename is not availble");

            var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "upload", filename);

            var memory = new MemoryStream();
            using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
            {
                await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);
            }
            memory.Position = 0;
            return File(memory, GetContentType(path), Path.GetFileName(path));
        }
        private string GetContentType(string path)
        {
            var types = GetMimeTypes();
            var ext = Path.GetExtension(path).ToLowerInvariant();
            return types[ext];
        }

        private Dictionary<string, string> GetMimeTypes()
        {
            return new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {".txt", "text/plain"},
                {".pdf", "application/pdf"},
                {".doc", "application/vnd.ms-word"},
                {".docx", "application/vnd.ms-word"},
                {".xls", "application/vnd.ms-excel"},
                {".xlsx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"},
                {".png", "image/png"},
                {".jpg", "image/jpeg"},
                {".jpeg", "image/jpeg"},
                {".gif", "image/gif"},
                {".csv", "text/csv"}
            };
        }
```